# How to map url in java web application

Tags: java, url, web, mapping

I have a question about java web applications.

Is there a way to map `url: index.jsp?lng=en` to: `index/en`?

Comment: I will be very grateful if you elaborate.

Comment: I have url index.jsp?lng=en. in brawser i want instead of that url, to show the following url: index/en. is there a way to do dat in java web applications

Comment: I dont which framework u r using: if jsf, have a look at pretty faces. If servlet, have a look at webfilters

Comment: i do not use any framework - standard java web application with JSP pages and servlets, that's it

Answer (score 0):

Take the host name from the `request` object if you are getting `HttpServletRequest` OR you can use regex to get the host name. `en` is a request parameter value which you can get using `request.getParameter("lng")`

```
URL aURL = new URL("index.jsp?lng=en");
System.out.println("hostname = " + aURL.getHost()); //index
```

then return String with `hostName + "/" + paramValue`